# Enabling SATA RAID on DL180 G5

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, bios

How to enable SATA RAID on DL180G5 E5405, because i did not find any equivalent option on the BIOS, nor any prompt for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although some very sophisticated disk controllers can easily be added to a DL180 G5 the basic server only comes with a fairly rudimentary south-bridge-based controller.

That said it can support RAID 0 or 1 via pressing F10 during POST.

From there the option you're looking for is under Advanced, then Disk Configuration.

Be aware that this controller only supports 4 disks, you'll need another controller for five or more disks. Let me know if you have a different controller as I'll be able to help with that if required too.

Comment: with F10 i may only enter the BIOS, and there no way to configure RAID from it.
In my case i have only Four disk and i don't find a way to configure my spares

Comment: It's inside the BIOS setup, below is a link to the manual from the HP explaining the whole thing with screenshots, start at page 6.  http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01311211/c01311211.pdf

Comment: I see i think that there are no RAID controller, in options i have only IDE, i'm confused

Comment: I find also in hp website that the SATA RAID has to be enabled before installing BIOS http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=3580698&prodTypeId=15351&objectID=c01473238 what does it mean

Comment: That page is about installing management/SNMP code on top of the array, you still need to create the actual array as detailed in the very thorough PDF I linked to.

Comment: Chopper3 thanks for your reply, but i did not have any RAID in configure controller options. as i said i have only IDE there is not other RAID option

Comment: Dude, seriously, if you have a DL180 G5 (and not another model) then you absolutely HAVE got a, quite poor, RAID controller built in and it is absolutely, positively configured using the BIOS/RBSU as outlined in that document and physically seen by my own increasingly-bloodshot eyes. Have you tried following that PDF's instructions?